# Gcloud ML-Engine Prection Error OOM 429

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I'm getting the following error when trying to use `gcloud ml-engine predict`

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.predict) HTTP request failed. Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Prediction server is out of memory, possibly because model size is too big.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}
```

My model size is 151 mb, I'm also using Tensorflow version 1.4 that does not requiere variables folder. When performing prediction it uses over 2gb. I'm using a modified version of inception.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the machines used for prediction have only 2 GB of RAM. We are working on bringing machines with more RAM to the service.

That said, "vanilla" inception models are usually about the same size on disk as you are reporting but tend to easily fit in 2 GB of RAM. Is the explosion of RAM expected given the changes that you've made?

Comment: Using local prediction the model uses over 2 GB of RAM when making a prediction.

Comment: If you believe the amount of RAM used is reasonable for your model, then we just need more RAM. To get notified when more RAM is available, please send an email to cloudml-feedback@google.com with your project and a reference to this post.